# Get WooCommerce product attribute taxonomies in a SQL query on WordPress database

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wpdb, sql

I am trying to retrieve a list of all my `attributes_name` values (carat, color, size etc) from the WooCommerce table `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` in WordPress database.

And here is my code from the below but getting the name of the attribute and not what's inside that column:

```
$sql = "SELECT attribute_name FROM wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['attribute_name'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Any idea how to retrieve whats inside them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WordPress to make a custom SQL query, you should always use the dedicated [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) Class and related methods as [`get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), this way:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT attribute_name
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
" );

if ( count($results) > 0) {
    $data = []; // Initializing

    // Loop through results objects
    foreach( $results as $result ) {
        // add each value to an array
        $data[] = $result->attribute_name . "<br>";
    }

    // output data of all rows
    echo implode( "<br>", $data );
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

**Better**, when you are querying one column of a table (as you are doing), you can use [`get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/) method this way:

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT attribute_name
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
" );

if ( count($results) > 0) {
    // output data of all rows
    echo implode( "<br>", $results );
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

---

**The best easy way** is to use WooCommerce [`wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_attribute_taxonomies.html#44-85) dedicated function:

```
$output = '<ul style="list-style:none;">';

// Loop through all Woocommerce product attributes
foreach( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() as $attribute ) {
    $attribute_label = $attribute->attribute_label; // Product attribute name
    $attribute_slug  = $attribute->attribute_name;  // Product attribute slug

    $output .= '<li class="'.$attribute_slug.'">' . $attribute_label . '</li>';
}
// Output
echo $output . '</ul>';
```

Related thread: [Get woocommerce product attributes to sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53742146/get-woocommerce-product-attributes-to-sidebar/53745324#53745324)

Comment: Hi thank you do you mind see below response

Comment: @AliRJ See my comment on your answer.

Comment: Thank you, this clears things for me.

Comment: Can I get your expertise on this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346795/how-to-retrieve-specific-product-attribute-value-in-an-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

and thank you so much fo your answer. This is very nice solution but I am still not getting the values and am only getting the attribute name or titles (like table headings). I need the rows of attribute for each product. So for example I have the attributes: carat, color, size, condition on my dashboard and with your code or mine I am only returning 
carat
color
size
condition 
I want to be able to retrieve values such as

product 1. carat [0.2], color [l], size[big], condition [excellent]
product 2. carat [0.90], color [g], size[small], condition [good]
product 3. ....

with this sql query I am a bit closer to retrieving all values: Please see

```
$sql = "SELECT p.`ID` AS 'Product ID', p.`post_title` AS 'Product Name', t.`term_id` AS 'Attribute Value ID', REPLACE(REPLACE(tt.`taxonomy`, 'pa_', ''), '-', ' ') AS 'Attribute Name', t.`name` AS 'Attribute Value' FROM `wp_posts` AS p INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` AS tr ON p.`ID` = tr.`object_id` INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` AS tt ON tr.`term_taxonomy_id` = tt.`term_id` AND tt.`taxonomy` LIKE 'pa_%' INNER JOIN `wp_terms` AS t ON tr.`term_taxonomy_id` = t.`term_id` WHERE p.`post_type` = 'product' AND p.`post_status` = 'publish' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row['Attribute Value'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: My actual answer is answering your initial question. This is not really what you asked in your initial question… So you should better ask a new question with that code. Also we don't know if your products are simple or variables (or both)… Or if you want to get that information for each product variation of a variable product. So try to make the things clear on your new question, as without you will not get useful answers.